# Error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I know that some have already posted this topic but after reviewed all the given answer, I can not find anything suit my case. I would be happy if someone can help me resolving my case.

I started getting my build failed as I've updated my Kotlin lib from 1.5.31 to 1.6.0. My Android Room `BaseDao` class can’t be compiled again. Below my `BaseDao` class:

```kotlin
interface BaseDao<T> {
    /**
     * Insert an object in the database.
     *
     */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(obj: T): Long

    /**
     * Insert an array of objects in the database.
     *
     * @param obj the objects to be inserted.
     */
    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(vararg obj: T): LongArray

    /**
     * Update an object from the database.
     *
     * @param obj the object to be updated
     */
    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun update(obj: T)

    /**
     * Delete an object from the database
     *
     * @param obj the object to be deleted
     */
    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(obj: T)
}

@Transaction
suspend inline fun <reified T> BaseDao<T>.insertOrUpdate(item: T) {
    if (insert(item) != -1L) return
    update(item)
}
```

After build:

> BaseDao.java:19: error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
> kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Long> continuation);
> error: Not sure how to handle insert method’s return type.
> public abstract java.lang.Object insert(T obj, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

This is how i call my `BaseDao` in one of my `Dao` class:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface CustomDao : BaseDao<CustomEntity> {
   
}
```

I've tried `@JvmSuppressWildcards` but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Have you marked `CustomEntity` of `CustomDao` with @Entity annotation? And, did you just upgrade the kotlin version or the room version as well?

Comment: Yes i've marked CustomEntity as @Entity annotation. I just upgrade the kotlin version not room. Am using the latest room version:  room_version = "2.3.0"

Comment: Just updating the Kotlin version caused this error?

Comment: Yes. but if i downgrade kotlin to 1.5.31, no problem

Comment: I experienced the same issue. Downgrade to 1.5.31 for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally found a solution to update Kotlin from 1.5.31 to 1.6.10
and my room version from 2.3.0 to 2.4.0.

The error I was getting, comes from a function I wrote in the embedded data class, as soon as I removed it then everything works.

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["device_id"],)
data class DetailedDataEntity(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "device_id", index = true)
    var deviceId: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "unix_timestamp")
    var unixTimestamp: Long,

    @Embedded(prefix = "data_")
    var data: DetailedData
)


data class DetailedData( @ColumnInfo(name = "nameFx") val nameFx: String) {
    companion object {
        @Ignore
        fun fromData(detailedData: Protobuf.Data): DetailedData {
            return DetailedData(nameFx = detailedData.nameFx)
        }
    }
}
```

```
    companion object {
         @Ignore
         fun fromData(detailedData: Protobuf.Data): DetailedData {
             return DetailedData(nameFx = detailedData.nameFx)
         }
    }
```

I've removed this companion object and then when I build the project, it's successfully passed. honestly, I do not know why this but I think it must have something to do with Google protobuf message associated with my embedded class.

Answer (score 2):

instead of kapt use ksp this will resolve the problem. It worked for me. For Kotlin 1.9.0 and above Google has introduced ksp over kapt for Room and Hilt dependency.

Comment: Yes. That's true. Follow this for reference https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp

Answer (score 1):

Please don't forget to update your Kotlin & Room version to the latest stable version in your gradle project file.

Look for latest version of Room on Android official doc and for latest version of Kotlin goto File->Settings->Language and Framework->Kotlin, then copy the digits after 1st hyphen. For ex, 212-1.7.10 , choose 1.7.10 and update your kotlin version in gradle.

It works!!

Answer (score 0):

Migrate from `kapt` to `ksp` compiler. Use this as a reference [migrate-to-ksp](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp)